# Query to fetch users not logged in for x hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a users table. What I m trying to do is, I want to count all the users who has not been logged in since 36 hours. Here is my query

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE last_loggedin >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 36 HOUR)
```

This works well, but this query also includes users who are not logged in for 5 years.

So in a result, I want to apply this 36 hours condition to only those who are not logged in for last 3 months.

**UPDATE**

For simplicity to understand. The above query results all users who are not logged in for 36 hours. The result might include the users who are not logged in for 48 hours, for 5 days, for 5 months, or even for 5 years. Say this yielded 10000 rows.

What I want to do is filter the `RESULT`, so that it only includes users who has not been logged in for 3 months, so that now remaining rows would be say 500.

So can this be achieved in one single query??

Comment: Please select an answer, this will hopefully discourage further copy-pasting :-)

Comment: Supplying a small data sample would save you from some of this awful answers

Comment: "I want to apply this 36 hours condition to only those who are not logged in for last 3 months." This does not make sense, and actually the answers below didn't go for it... Did you mean "... to only those with last log in during the last 3 months"?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz perhaps this is some kind of social experiment... And we are part of it, voluntarily!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, like my query above, it includes user who has not been logged in for  5 years as well in the result. I only want to include the user  who are not logged in for last 3 months in the result.

Comment: No, your query above looks for users who logged in in the last 36 hours. `>=`  should be changed to `<=`

Comment: Still I don't understand what you say. Please give an example if you want to discuss this further. Your problem is clearly (a) very easy to solve once properly defined and (b) unclearly stated, which is the reason of all this mess. Please help us resolve the situation.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, please check my update. Hopefully I m being able to make you understand this time??

Comment: @WatsMyName no, sorry... To begin with, you still claim that your original query solves some version of your problem, so perhaps there is a misunderstanding there: `last_loggedin >= now - 36 hours` (pseudocode) seems to give the users who **did actually log in** during the last 36 hours. No?

Comment: Voted to close. A data sample is not more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Since dates are represented in days 36 hours is 36/24 days. So selecte all users whose difference from now to last logged in date is between 36/24 and 90 days (3 months).

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),last_loggedin) BETWEEN 36/24 AND 90
```

Comment: **(1)** wrong results since `datediff` result is rounded **(2)** if there is an index on `last_loggedin` it won't be used with this syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id FROM users
 WHERE last_loggedin >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 36 HOUR) 
and  last_loggedin <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE last_loggedin >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 36 HOUR) 
AND last_loggedin  <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

Comment: **(1)** What is wrong with `BETWEEN`? **(2)** wrong direction of conditions (>= / <=)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yes you can use BETWEEN also

Answer (score -2):

You can just use sub-query like this

```
select T.user_id,T.last_loggedin from
  (
  SELECT user_id,last_loggedin FROM users WHERE last_loggedin >= now() and last_loggedin<= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 month)
  ) as T

  where T.last_loggedin>=now() and T.last_loggedin>= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 36 HOUR)
```

Comment: Why not use the much simpler `select ... from T where ... ` way, as so many answers already suggested? But it is amusing to see that so many people prefer this type of answer, isn't it?

Comment: One of the worst answers I've ever seen. `WHERE last_loggedin >= now()`? seriously? Who ever up-voted it should be ashamed. And sub-query is not a magic word. It is not needed here.

Comment: `last_loggedin >= now()` this will always give zero records